# C#: FindWindowEx not working as anticipated

Tags: c#, visual-studio, pinvoke, dllimport

Ok first off I'm new to C# so this may be something really simple, I've just not found the answer throughout Google/SO.

I have a class where I'm trying to use FindWindowEx, however, Visual Studio isn't allowing me to use 'null' arguments and I'm unsure why.

So far the class has this code:

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr handleParent, IntPtr handleChild, string className, string WindowName);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    public void SomeWindow()
    {

        String someHwnd = FindWindowEx(IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, "SomeWindowClass", NULL);

    }
```

As it is written, it is telling me that 'NULL' doesn't exist in the current context. I've also tried writing as:

```
FindWindowEx(null, null, "SomeWindowClass", null)
```

This gives errors under the first two 'null's saying "Argument #: Cannot convert from 'null' to 'IntPtr'" (The 'null' actually has < and > surrounding it although SO isn't displaying it with them)

The Windows Dev Center says I should be able to use it as I am though which is here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633500(v=vs.85).aspx

Like I said it may be something incredibly simple, I just don't have enough experience in C# to figure it out.

Comment: why won't you just try `FindWindowEx(IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, "SomeWindowClass", null);`

Comment: sTrenat, because then it red underlines the whole call saying "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.IntPtr' to 'string'. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Oh wait -- you're asking two different questions. Your title is "FindWindowEx not accepting null arguments", but you already pretty much solved that in your question body, you show `IntPtr.Zero` yourself. The return type problem is different from that.

Comment: No sorry, I wasn't aware that it was the type that was causing the issue. I thought it was the null arguments, sorry. EDIT: I've just updated the question title to reflect this. However, being such a simple case of just assigning the variable to an incorrect type, I'm not sure if it is a valuable question that will help others too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FindWindow return type is IntPtr, whereas you are trying to assign it to string.

Try this.

```
IntPtr wnd = FindWindowEx(IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, "SomeWindowClass", null);
```

Comment: Perfect, that has resolved the errors. Had a feeling it would be something simple. I was using a string so that I could write in message box to test that what I'm attempting works. Thanks a bunch :D